# 18.04 Ubuntu system fails to boot, instead stops in initramfs

Tags: 18.04

[image]

Look at the pic when I open same problem occur

Comment: get into the bios and see if uefi secure boot is enabled, try to boot with and without uefi and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: After enabling secure boot MODSIGN: couldn't get UEFI db list removed but still it showing  couldn't get size ...